# How do I use a python dictionary for placing tiles in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

```
    for blocks in TileGroup:
        TileDict=[]

        lmb,rmb = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0],pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]

        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mouse_hover = blocks.rect.collidepoint(mouse_x,mouse_y)
        if lmb:
            if mouse_hover:
                blocks.kill()
        if rmb:
            
            x = mouse_x - (mouse_x % 20) 
            y = mouse_y - (mouse_y % 20) 
            pos = x / y
            
            if pos not in TileDict:
                platform = ground(x, y)
                TileDict.append(pos)
                TileGroup.add(platform)
```

Hi, I'm new to dictionaries and I kind of understand how they work but I don't know how to implement them into make game, I want to be able to delete tiles and place them back, right now I can do both but it places a bunch of the tiles in the same spot when I right click, making it extremely laggy. I have looked up dictionaries but still don't know how I would use them here, I also tried arrays but someone said I should start using dictionaries when coding.

Comment: You mention `dictionaries` but `TileDict = []` is a list.

Comment: Is the game board a bunch of squares?

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
Without having more code, I have an initial suggestion, move TileDict =[]
out of the loop it is being initialized each pass through the loop.
"""
TileDict = []
for blocks in TileGroup:
    lmb, rmb = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0], pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]
    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mouse_hover = blocks.rect.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y)
    if lmb:
        if mouse_hover:
            blocks.kill()
    if rmb:
        x = mouse_x - (mouse_x % 20)
        y = mouse_y - (mouse_y % 20)
        pos = x / y
        if pos not in TileDict:
            platform = ground(x, y)
            TileDict.append(pos)
            TileGroup.add(platform)
```